How to search in autocomplete with typeahead as false
I previously used the vuetify which has combobox. Basically in the combobox we can add items manually by typing in the field and also it allows to search through the existing items list as well.
I want to replicate the same thing using prime vue.
Here i am able to add the manual items but not able to search through the list. Is there any way to search through the list as well?
<AutoComplete v-model="value" dropdown multiple :suggestions="items" :typeahead="false" @complete="search" />

import { ref } from "vue";

const value = ref("");
const items = ref([]);

const search = (event) => {
    items.value = ['1','abc efg txt','3']
    if (event.query) {
        items.value = items.value.filter(function (item) {
            return item.search(event.query) >= 0
        })
    }
}
</script>

